# How to check vulnerable component and its version in any APK?

Tags: penetration-test, android, appsec

I have given an app to test, on which I ran a quick scan in composition tool like Protecode, It shows all component (like okhttp, protobuf,okhttp etc.) used and existing vulnerability.

My question is, if I want to list all component and its version/vulnerability manually, so how can we do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Owasp dependency check is one of the ways to go. It downloads all the latest vulnerability listings for the dependencies and than checks your app dependencies against them.

**Tool:**

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check

**Guide:**

https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-scanning-your-app-for-known-vulnerabilities-421384603fc5